# Scraping partial table with VBA

Tags: vba, xmlhttprequest, scrape

I'm trying to scrape *5 colums of the table on https://data.goaloong.net/1x2/.
All single row on each single row.

*see screen

**MY CURRENT CODE**

```
Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Set html = New HTMLDocument

url = "https://data.goaloong.net/1x2/"

http.Open "GET", url, False
http.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
http.send
    While http.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText    
   
With Sheets("table")    
    Set HTMLAtab = html.getElementsByTagName("table")(0)

    For Each HTMLArow In HTMLAtab.Rows
        iRow = iRow + 1
        iCol = 0
        For Each HTMLAcel In HTMLArow.Cells
            iCol = iCol + 1
            Cells(iRow, iCol) = HTMLAcel.innerText
        Next HTMLAcel
    Next HTMLArow              
End With
```

[image]

Desired output:

| league | time | home | away | compare |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UAE RL | 17-03 14:45 | Ajman Reserve | Al-Wasl (R) | http://..... |
| UAE RL | 17-03 14:45 | Al-Sharjah (R) | Al Ahli Dubai Reserve | http://..... |
| etc | ... | ... | ... | ... |

**UPDATED CODE**

```
    .Cells(i, 1) = html.getElementsByClassName("black-down f-white")(0).innerText
    .Cells(i, 2) = html.getElementsByClassName("en")(0).getAttribute("data-tf")
    .Cells(i, 3) = html.getElementsByClassName("team")(0).innerText
    .Cells(i, 4) = html.getElementsByClassName("td")(2).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText
```

I tried various methods but I still failing.

Comment: The second column `Time` is not present in the xhr solution.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

```
Sub TryThis()
    Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim objTable As Object
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lngTable As Long
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim ActRw As Long
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastColumn As Long

    objIE.Navigate "https://data.goaloong.net/1x2/"

    Do Until objIE.ReadyState = 4 And Not objIE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = objIE.Document.body.innerHTML
    With HTMLDoc.body
        Set objTable = .getElementsByTagName("table")
        For lngTable = 0 To objTable.Length - 1
            For lngRow = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length - 1
                For lngCol = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells.Length - 1
                If lngCol = 0 Or lngCol = 1 Or lngCol = 2 Or lngCol = 3 Or lngCol = 11 Or lngCol = 12 Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActRw + lngRow + 1, lngCol + 1) = objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).innerText
                End If
                Next lngCol
            Next lngRow
            ActRw = ActRw + objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length + 1
        Next lngTable
    End With
    objIE.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your code, I have this result:

https://imgur.com/7L48LXN

My goal is https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOOV2.jpg, possibly using xmlhttp

Comment: It's because those are merged cells, or whatever you want to call it, in the web site.  I would avoid merged cells at all costs.

Comment: I noticed the content i need is in <td rowspan="2" ......> change the class